# Go, can not replace new module with local version

Tags: go, module

I am creating a new private module which will ultimately be stored in bitbucket.
The structure of this module is the following:

```
package1Directory
package2Directory
package3Directory
go.mod
go.sum
```

The go.mod file look like this:

```
module newModule

go 1.17

require (
      //..,, bunch of external modules 
)
```

As still in early stages of dev, I do not wish to push it to bitbucket yet. But I still want to use it in other local project for testing purpose.

On this local project I have the following code:

On my different go files:

```
import ("bitbucket.org/myRepo/myModules/newModule")

//Do something with newModule
```

On my go.mod file:

```
require (
    //Commented until actually pushed and versioned 
    //bitbucket.org/myRepo/myModules/newModule
...
)

//Specify to use local version instead of remote version
replace bitbucket.org/myRepo/myModules/newModule => ../myModules/newModule/
```

However this does not work as I hoped.
When running the command go mod tidy, I am getting the following error:

```
    bitbucket.org/myRepo/myModules/newModule: module bitbucket.org/myRepo/myModules/newModule@latest found (v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000, replaced by ../myModules/newModule/), but does not contain package bitbucket.org/myRepo/myModules/newModule
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, if someone can direct me on the right step, it would be much appreciated !

Comment: You can't remove the module from `require`, you still require it even though you are replacing the location.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add it if the module does not exist yet in remote repo? I do not even have a version to add.

Comment: Either use `go get` or add it directly to `go.mod`. If you want `go mod tidy` to work you also have to add an actual package to the module for it to find.

Comment: It does not solve the problem it does add it do the //indirect requirement, but I still have the same error

Comment: Without a real example I'm only guessing, but `but does not contain package ...` means there is no package in the module, have you created that package yet? I suggest reading through the Getting Started guide, specifically the sections on [Creating a Module](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module)

Comment: So the problem was that I did created the package, but did not not realize it should be in the root, and not its own directory. So the basically path was wrong. Thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 0):

As prompted by the error message

```
... but does not contain package bitbucket.org/myRepo/myModules/newModule
```

You should edit you `go.mod` of module `bitbucket.org/myRepo/myModules/newModule` as (notice the first line of declaration of the module):

```
module bitbucket.org/myRepo/myModules/newModule

go 1.17

require (
      //..,, bunch of external modules 
)
```

And you must add version tag in format like `v1.2.3`, in `require` and `replace` clauses, in the `go.mod` of the other modules importing your `newModule`:

```
require bitbucket.org/myRepo/myModules/newModule v0.0.0

replace bitbucket.org/myRepo/myModules/newModule v0.0.0 => ../myModules/newModule/
```

Refer to https://go.dev/doc/modules/managing-dependencies#local_directory.